# Get Cell according to its number in Board data structure Cell[][] without passing 2 FOR loops

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee, multidimensional-array

I need to create board game that made up from cells.
The board should be 5X5 ==> 25 cells
I wonder what data structure to use: `Cell[][]` ("matrix") or `ArrayList<Cell>`.
I chose `Cell[][]`, java two-dimensional array in Java ("matrix") of Cells.

Every cell has number.
this is how it looks in the matrix:
[image]

For example:

```
matrix[0][2] = Cell number 3  
matrix[2][4] = Cell number 15  
matrix[3][3] = Cell number 19
```

I am having problem how to get Cell according to its number.

For example if I want to get cell number 19 I need to pass on all the rows and than all the columns with two FOR loops.
In ArrayList its easier, just use 'get(int index)' function.

Is there a better way to get Cell according to its number when I work with data structure of `Cell[][]` ?
I though to have the row and column number of the cell when I builds it:

```
public class Cell   
{  
    private int m_RowNum;  
    private int m_ColNum;  
    private int m_Number;  
}
```

But not sure how to do it.
Maybe I can build some function that can get the Cell without passing on two FOR loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a formula to convert the cell number into its associated two-dimensional coordinate:

```
row = floor((number - 1) / columns);
column = (number - 1) % columns;
```

So for example, for cell number `1`, you get:

```
row = floor((1 - 1) / 5) = 0 
column = (1 - 1) % 5 = 0;
```

Which means cell number `1` is at `(0, 0)`

and for cell number `2`, you get:

```
row = floor((2 - 1) / 5) = 0
column = (2 - 1) % 5 = 1
```

Which means that cell number `2` is at `(0, 1)`.

Let's pick a non-trivial one, say `17`. You get:

```
row = floor((17 - 1) / 5) = floor(16 / 5) = 3
column = (17 - 1) % 5 = 16 % 5 = 1
```

Which means the cell number `17` is at `(3, 1)`.

Comment: This "floor" is not meant to be java.lang.Math.floor.

Comment: @laune It would be acceptable in this case to forcibly cast it to an `int` I think.

Comment: Integer division results in an int.

Comment: @laune But `Math.floor` itself returns a `double`; I was referring to the return value.

Comment: @VivinPaliath OK, it looks like that it works. How can I be sure it will work for any board? for example for board 8x8 ?

Comment: @VivinPaliath OK, so why use Math.floor in the first place?

Comment: @EviatarG. It so happens that the operations of integer division and remainder are fundamentals of arithmetic which doesn't change at random. And, if it would *not* work for an 8x8 board, then this remarkable fact would have been discovered long ago.

Comment: @laune You're absolutely right; there's no reason. I was writing it out as a mathematical notation, not as Java code.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to hide the implementation in a class Board and give it methods

```
Cell getByRowCol( int row, int col )
Cell getByNumber( int number )
```

and use what appears to be more convenient at the moment. If either method turns out to be useless, you can drop it later. If the chosen implmentation is not efficient, you can change it without impact on the interface of Board and the places where these methods are called.

Not that there is any danger w.r.t. efficiency, neither with an array nor with an ArrayList. But information hiding is "best practice" for all such scenarios.